# Add fragment and animate another fragment to a new position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I hope to find an answer to the following question here:

I want to build an UI with the following behavior:

State 1:
After the activity loaded you can see a ListFragment on the left right side of the screen.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Activity                                                                       |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                  +-----------+|
|                                                                  |Fragment1  ||
|                                                                  |           ||
|                                                                  |           ||
|                                                                  |           ||
|                                                                  |           ||
|                                                                  |           ||
|                                                                  |           ||
|                                                                  +-----------+|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

State 2: After the User clicked on a item in the ListFragment, the fragment should animate to the left to have space for another fragment(2)

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Activity                                                                       |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                    +------------++-----------+|
|                                                    |Fragment1   ||Fragment2  ||
|                                                    |            ||           ||
|                                                    |            ||           ||
|                                                    |            ||           ||
|                                                    |            ||           ||
|                                                    |            ||           ||
|                                                    |            ||           ||
|                                                    +------------++-----------+|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I use the support-v4 library for the fragments. i tried this possibilities:

1. Via Frame-Layouts: Add the fragment in the code, when clicked on the list, remove the fragment, add it again on another Framelayout then add the second Fragment. - The question here is: how can i animate the move of fragment one from framelayout one to framelayout two.
2. Via Animation: i used the NineOldAndroid Library an tried to move the layout via different values. But I alwasy get unexpected behaviors: the position was good, but there where no more touch reactions on the list and stuff like this.
3. Via changing the LayoutParams: I also didnt understand how to animate this.

   Sorry that I dont give any code here, this is because I always changed everything to try another solution.

I hope someone can give me any advice how i solve my problem or any hints where i can find information or ideas to this question.

Thanks a lot!